# Nutch - Visit few pages again and again to find new links

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, nutch2

I have setup Nutch 1.17 to crawl few thousand domains with inlinks crawl only. One of my main requirement is I should have to visit home pages again and again (lets say after 2 hour) and if there is any new page, then only that should be crawled.

What should be the best possible way ?
I am thinking to crawl run injector job again and again to crawl home pages. Is it the right way  ? Meanwhile how should I ensure that inlinks are also going to fetch with time.

Comment: Are you able to find the solution

Comment: Yes, I found a solution. In seed, you should specify the revisit time e.g., 4 hours. Then, those URLs will be selected again after 4 hours.

Comment: may i know the parameter in nutch

Comment: May I know are you using the nutch webui @Shafiq

Comment: May I know how nutch knows new page is added then crawl it.Can you help me.

Comment: In seed file, lets say you want to recrawl seed URL, after 60 minute. Then this will be the seed file format.
http://humkinar.pk/ nutch.fetchInterval.fixed=60 userType=open_source

Comment: During fetching, new links are found that are parsed in parser job. Then updatedb job simply create a new record (row) in the db. From this DB, new URLs are selected based on their meta info.

Comment: Please spend some time on Nutch documentation/manual.

Comment: may I know what is modified time in nutch i see some columns as  modified time.

Comment: Thanks for info.may i know what is difference between db.fetch.interval.default andnutch.fetchInterval.fixed. I crawled some urls it marked as retry fetch interval is 30 days and db_unfecthed urls as retryintervaldays is 30 days but when crawl next round db_gone as retry days is 45 days on what basis this incremented the 15 days.

Comment: bin/nutch inject $CRAWL_PATH/crawldb http://wisconsinrealtyexecutives.com        nutch.score=100 nutch.fetchInterval.fixed=10 userType=open_source -update
It is not working it is showing like this 20/11/09 11:33:53 INFO crawl.Injector: Injector: Found invalid argument "nutch.score=100"

Comment: May i know what is wrong in the command.

Comment: These arguments should be tab separated. Please have a look on Nutch wiki for this

Comment: Thanks I want to remove the urls which are not crawlable and not working from crawldb.

Comment: Brother I have to check it also. No idea at this time

Comment: Will nutch shows the next fetch time for urls because i can't see the next fetch time.